Verifying smart contracts deployed via Gnosis Safe Multisig on Etherscan using Gnosis Multisig
Is it possible to verify a smart contract using Gnosis safe multisig? 
If this is the case, could you please elaborate on the recommended approach or most effective method for verifying contracts that have been deployed through the Gnosis Safe Multisig Wallet on Etherscan using the Gnosis Multisig?

Proxy contracts (safes) that have been deployed using official proxy factories should be natively verified. For contracts that have been deployed through a safe (but are not safes themselves), the verify procedure should be the same than with contracts deployed with regular EOAs.
Please let me know if that helped solve your question; Best, Louis
